# 10' PVC Schedule 40 vs ABS sun sail support post. Life expectancy, wind and UV damage

Tags: pvc, post, support, abs

I'm setting some 6' T-posts deeper then usual ( down to like 4') for a simple fence project and i have a few spots where i want set up sun sail triangle from 10' high to 8' in about a 15' x 15' area.

I was thinking of just finding 3 regular  1 1/2 or 2" x 10' (depending on fit) Schedule 40 PCV pipes.. painting them for aesthetics and possible UV protection and then slipping them over the T-Posts and putting in some pins or screws to keep them in place and possible pushing them a foot into the ground as well.

The site is in Central Florida.

How much of benefit for the extra cost of ABS vs PVC if i plan to paint them?  Any particular paint going to work best ? last longer?

Would 6' of pipe with no support bend too much with the wind?  sched 40 is pretty rigid. The T-post are in really strong.

Comment: If using PVC, choose electrical conduit, which is already sun resistant (paint for appearance if you like, but you're not depending on that the way you are with PVC pipe, which quickly turns brittle with sun exposure.) While going there, spend a few more bucks and choose schedule 80 - a sail puts on some serious forces when the wind blows.

Comment: PVC  is flexible, ABS, more rigid but somewhat flexible. They both may snap if bent to far. I think i would use metal pipe, Which could also bent a kink/fold over if the wind gets a hold of the sail that is not secured well.

Comment: was thinking of using bungy chord in place of string.

Answer (score 1):

I would never even consider using 1.5" or 2" PVC or ABS piping of any schedule as a structural member; expecially for the application that you describe. These materials can flex and given some aging or overextended stress could fail dramatically.

Sure you may be able to make 5" or 6" diameter thick walled piping work in this application but the cost of that type of product should easily guide you back to some type of steel tubing whether that be square, round or rectangular cross section.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check fence contractors in your area for sufficiently-tall chain link fence posts.  They're made in huge lengths and various diameters; but home improvement stores generally carry only the sizes homeowners commonly buy.  You can use fence hardware to hook the sail onto your posts, too.